# Nivo Slider - Previous slide doesn't disappear until next slide is fully loaded creating image overlap

Tags: nivo-slider

Everything working fine with my slider except the previous slide stays on the screen with full opacity until the new one completely loads.  Then the last one finally disappears from behind the new one.

Weird glitch.  I've used Nivo several times and not sure why I'm seeing this on my site.  I reloaded the default package files and still nothing.